# Validation on page refresh

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

my input fields have an `<f:ajax>` object attached to make validation via pressing TAB possible:

```
<h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.property}">
    <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" />
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@this" />
</h:inputText>
```

If there are any validation errors, they will be displayed via a custom component similar to `<h:messages>` and the input boxes will be styled via a custom `PhaseListener`.

I have implemented a custom Faces Validator to skip validation:

```
public class CustomValidator {

public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (skipValidation(context)) {
        return;
    }
    //Validation code goes here
}
```

This gives me the option to skip bean validation based on some condition, e.g. switching to another editor view and saving the (maybe wrong) data in the backing bean.

Now, my problem occurs when refreshing the current page (either via pressing F5, hitting the same link in the navigation bar or similar). The obviously wrong data in the backing is displayed correctly, as intended, but it should also be marked as invalid. Thus I need a way to invoke the validation on every page load (currently it's invoked via the `<f:ajax>` objects only).

I tried fiddling with something like this

```
<f:ajax event="load" execute="editform" render="editform"/>
```

attached to `<h:body>`. This works, but the site is drawn twice - which I wouldn't really care if there was no evil flickering due toe the page first being drawn, then being validated & updated via the ajax request.

I've searched for hours for a solution to this problem, maybe I just searched in the wrong direction. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Wait .. The bean is thus session scoped??

Comment: Hi @BalusC, sorry for my late response. Yes, the bean (well, not the bean directly, but the object holding the bean, from which I reference the bean) is `@SessionScoped` to keep the bean for the entire session, not only the request. Is that the problem? I can add more information about the exact use case WHY I did it this way if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `@SessionScoped` bean to back a page; it's a JSF design-smell (if there's such a thing)

---

Use the `preRenderView` event to trigger (or check) whatever validation logic you choose on page load.  As a start:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.validate}" rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}" />
```

1. The `<f:event/>` tag registers an event listener on your page.
2. The `type="preRenderView"` attribute stipulates that the event should be executed just before the page is loaded
3. `rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}"` is going to ensure that the event is loaded only when the same page is being refreshed, and not when it's being loaded for the first time
4. `listener` will refer to a backing bean method in which you carry out the validation that you require. In this listener, you can throw a `ValidationException` and also queue `FacesMessages` appropriately

---

Alternatives:

1. You can reference the component's value in a `viewParam` and attach the same validator to that component:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="theParam" rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}" value="param['form:input2']" validator="customValidator"/>
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   What this would do is attempt to resubmit the value of the `input2` component as a view parameter. A view parameter (in this usage) is a `UIComponent` like any other, and is subject to the same conversion/validation semantics.
2. You could also pass the entire component as an attribute on the `viewParam`, if you want a more involved handling of the content of that component. First bind the `input2` component to the page scope:

   ```
    <h:inputText id="input2" binding="#{input2}" value="#{bean.property}">
        <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" />
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@this" />
    </h:inputText>
   ```

   Then pass the component as an attribute:

   ```
     <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="theParam" rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}" validator="customValidator"/>
            <f:attribute name="input2" value="#{input2}"/>
     </f:metadata>
   ```

You can then retrieve the value in your validator:

```
      UIInput input2= (UIInput)component.getAttributes().get("input2");

      String input2Value= input2.getSubmittedValue().toString();
```

Comment: `<f:event>` doesn't support the `rendered` attribute (it isn't an `UIComponent`) and the `FacesContext` doesn't have a `isIsPostback()` nor `getIsPostback()` method. `ValidationException` isn't part of JSF API and even then JSF wouldn't catch validation exceptions from there like as it does in process validations phase. Have you tested your answer before posting it?

Comment: Even if it would work that way, how would I trigger the usage of my `CustomValidator` from the backing bean listener method?

Comment: @BalusC, my mistake, I meant  `facesContext.postBack`. `f:event` does have the `rendered` attribute in my JSF 2.2 distribution (shows up in the code complete and everything). Haven't had time to test it through. I'll give it a go in the morning

Comment: @kolossus How would I trigger my CustomValidator faces Validator from `bean.validate`? I'd really like to give you that bounty and accept that answer :)

Comment: @INK - Sorry I've been incredibly busy. You can manually trigger validation from the backend by calling `processValidations` on the component that holds the input value. I haven't posted it because I haven't tested it yet (see "no time" above). I'll have that up shortly

Comment: @kolossus Ok, with that information, I should be able to fix the problem. I will test your solution and ask for more, if needed. In the mean time, I will grant you the bounty and accept the answer :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sadly, invoking `FacesContext.getCurrentContext().getViewRoot().processValidators(FaccesContext.getCurrentContext())` does not invoke the validiation again. I'm trying to get more inside in the code via grepcode, but it seems that it's not possible to invoke the validation at all. The validation is only invoked AFTER the first page rendering (when submitting a form, refreshing the page, etc. pp.).

Comment: @INK - Posted some alternatives. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You could hide your form and use the **onevent** attribute of your JSF-AJAX node.
It will be called, when the AJAX response is fetched and sets your form visible.

So the whole process could be like:

1. Make the form invisible via css. Like `<form style="display:none">`
2. Your `<f:ajax>` element is being processed.
3. After getting response its attribute *onevent* is called and will set your form visible.

Hint: For a better Look&Feel you could use JQuery for displaying the form. Use it like:

`$("#myform").fadeIn();`